# 'mono shared runtime' always deployed to android device

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, apk, xamarin

I'm trying to create an APK using xamarin.android & visual studio 2012, but the option for 'package ... apk file' is disabled - and i believe this is a bug as described here: (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10530).

However, an apk is still created when deployed to a device, the problem is i only want one APK which contains everything (so i can deploy it via a web server), but when building this way, even in release with 'use shared runtime' unticked, 'mono shared runtime' is still installed on the device. I've created an issue on it here: (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11419) but no reply yet..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just want one APK for release, correct?  In that case, it is possible to build a APK from the command line. If you're on Windows, you can automate this by using the following Powershell script as a template:

```
# First clean the Release target.
msbuild.exe HelloWorld.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Clean

# Now build the project, using the Release target.
msbuild.exe HelloWorld.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:PackageForAndroid

# At this point there is only the unsigned APK - sign it.
# The script will pause here as jarsigner prompts for the password.
# It is possible to provide they keystore password for jarsigner.exe by adding an extra command line parameter -storepass, for example
#    -storepass <MY_SECRET_PASSWORD>
# If this script is to be checked in to source code control then it is not recommended to include the password as part of this script.
& 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\jarsigner.exe' -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1  -keystore ./xample.keystore -signedjar ./bin/Release/mono.samples.helloworld-signed.apk ./bin/Release/mono.samples.helloworld.apk publishingdoc

# Now zipalign it.  The -v parameter tells zipalign to verify the APK afterwards.
& 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign.exe' -f -v 4 ./bin/Release/mono.samples.helloworld-signed.apk ./helloworld.apk
```

Building from the command line is also possible on the Mac. I will typically automate this with a Rake build file (you'll need to install the gem for the .NET Rake tasks from [Albacore](http://albacorebuild.net/)). The following is a rakefile you can use as a template:

```
require 'albacore'

@file_version = "2.0.0.0"
@keystore     = "../keystores/opgenorth-release-key.keystore"
@alias_name   = "mytrips"
@input_apk    = "EmploymentStandardsJudgments.Android/bin/Release/net.opgenorth.esj.apk"
@signed_apk   = "EmploymentStandardsJudgments.Android/bin/Release/net.opgenorth.esj-signed.apk"
@final_apk    = "deploy/AlbertaEmploymentJudgments.apk"

task :default => [:clean, :versioning, :build, :sign] 

desc "Remove the bin and obj directories."
task :clean do
  rm_rf "EmploymentStandardsJudgments.Android/bin"
    rm_rf "EmploymentStandardsJudgments.Android/obj"
end

desc "Update the build number before compiling."
assemblyinfo :versioning do |asm|
    asm.input_file  = "EmploymentStandardsJudgments.Android/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs"
    asm.output_file = "EmploymentStandardsJudgments.Android/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs"
    asm.version = @file_version
    asm.file_version = @_file_version
end

desc "Compiles the project."
xbuild :build do |msb|
    msb.solution = "EmploymentStandardsJudgments.Android/EmploymentStandardsJudgments.Android.csproj"
    msb.properties = { :configuration => :release }
    msb.targets [ :Clean, :Build, :SignAndroidPackage ]
end

desc "Signs and zip aligns the APK."
task :sign do 
    sh "jarsigner",  "-verbose", "-sigalg", "MD5withRSA", "-digestalg", "SHA1", "-keystore",  @keystore, "-signedjar", @signed_apk, @input_apk, @alias_name
    sh "zipalign", "-f", "-v", "4", @signed_apk, @final_apk
end

desc "Install the APK on a device."
task :install do
    %x[adb shell pm uninstall -k net.opgenorth.esj.android]
    %x[adb install deploy/AlbertaEmploymentJudgments.apk]
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: awsome! it works! thank you so much! <3

i used the msbuild.exe (.net 4.0) version